# Multiple Webservices with shared web.config logging to separate flat files with Ent Lib

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, logging, enterprise-library

I'm working on a project where I'm required to use Enterprise Library v.3.1.1.0 Logging block (wish it was log4net or nlog, but I don't get a choice).  We have an IIS application where several WCF webservices are hosted, and they share a single web.config file.  This is also something I'm not at liberty to change.

None of these services had any logging implemented previously.

So it's pretty straight forward to use the Ent Lib Config utility to set up a rolling flat file listener, and log to a text file the way I want.  The problem I'm having is configuring it properly though so each service can have their own separate log file, while they still all share the same web.config.

I've gone through several tutorials, but I'm not understanding how to do this.

Any tips?

Comment: Not sure why this would be closed as exact duplicate; it's a completely different question than the one that was linked to, and the answer at the linked question doesn't answer my question at all.  I need to know how to log to multiple flat files, from multiple different web applications that share the same web.config.

Comment: The configuration is static so there will be one file per configured trace listener.  You could have each service log to a different category which uses a different trace listener.

Comment: Thanks Tuzo, I guess I didn't really grasp the concept of Categories being used like that.  I suppose I'd have to somehow enforce from each different service that they only log to their own category - but I suppose I can document that in comments or something.  Is there any way you know of to use reflection to route log events by originating class?  I know you can do that in log4net out of the box.

Comment: There is no out of the box way to use reflection to route log events.  It might be possible but you will have to write some code.  You could write a Logger facade class to set the category based on the callers namespace.  (Also note that there is no namespace wildcard matching like Log4Net.)

Comment: @Tuzo, I've implemented your suggestion of logging to separate Categories for each service, and it works perfect.  Also, your suggestion of writing a facade that uses reflection to automatically direct logging to a certain category based on class or namespace works too.  If you write this as an answer, I will mark it accepted and upvote it; it's a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in the web.config is static so there will be one file per configured trace listener. One approach to achieve one file per service is to have each service log to a different category and each category uses a different trace listener.  This could even be done programmatically so that services can add their own trace listener's at runtime although this is a bit more advanced than updating the configuration file manually (e.g. ensure service is added only once as well as ensuring that when the configuration is updated it is thread-safe).

Enterprise Library does not have anything analogous to log4net's hierarchical loggers so there is no out of the box way to use reflection to route log messages based on the originating class. It might be possible but you will have to write some code. You could write a Logger facade class to set the category based on the callers namespace. (Also note that there is no namespace wildcard matching like log4net.)